# UnityEditor Add item in List of ExposedReference

Tags: c#, unity-editor

I'm working on a list of exposed reference of scene gameobject, It is close to be ready, but when I add an item, and the last item is already assigned it gets fully copied, exposedName and defaultValue.

[Video of current behaviour](https://streamable.com/8man6b)

I tried to add a callback when an Item gets added, the code runs, but don't know how to clear the value and create a new exposedReference without break the copied one. any help?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `ExposedProperties` have all the same `exposedName`. That's the ID that is used to identify the scene object linked to it.

If all ExposedProperties have the same `exposedName` then they point to the same object no matter what you do.

I tried re-assigning `exposedName` if it's the default value but this is unreliable.

```
public static class ExposedReferenceExtensions
{
    public static bool FixExposedReference<T>(
        this ExposedReference<T> self
    ) where T : Object
    {
        if (self.exposedName == default(PropertyName))
            self.exposedName = GUID.Generate().ToString();
    }
}
```